# multiple login routes using ember-cli-simple-auth

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am trying to configure a basic ember-cli app using authentication via ember-cli-simple-auth and want to have a dedicated 'guest' login page and a different 'admin' login page (authorizing to different **serverTokenEnpoint**'s).

I have the 'guest' page working, i.e. if a user tries to browse to a protected route (page) then they are redirected to the default **/login** route and can login Ok.

What I can't figure out is how to have a user that browse's to **/admin/xyz** route that they then  get redirected (using to **/admin/login** which in turn will authenticate to a different **serverTokenEnpoint** to the default.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve the above?

Thanks.

an example protected 'guest' route file looks like:

FILE: ***/app/routes/protected.js***

```
import Ember from 'ember';

import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

And the environment configs contain:

FILE: ***/app/config/environment.js***

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer',
    store: 'simple-auth-session-store:local-storage',
    crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://www.domain.com/token',
                         'http://www.domain.com'
   ]
};
```

I even tried to override the default **authenticationRoute** in my ***/app/routes/admin.js*** file like below but did not work:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,{
    authenticationRoute: 'admin.login'
});
```

---

So to simplify the process following Marco's suggestion I now have:

Note:  AT the moment this does not work.. @marcoow do you have any thoughts where im going wrong?

This is using ember-cli with the follow firebug output:

```
AuthenticatorBase A (unknown mixin)  ***<- IS this expected????***
CustomAuthenticator B (unknown mixin)
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember                       : 1.7.0
DEBUG: Ember Data                  : 1.0.0-beta.9
DEBUG: Handlebars                  : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery                      : 1.11.1
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth           : 0.6.4
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth OAuth 2.0 : 0.6.4
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

and if I put my manual override code back in see previous answer it will work, but since I want to use the same oauth2 authentication just to a different URL, I like the idea of just being able to override the **TokenEndpoint** with a custom authenticator.

***file: app/initializers/simple-auth-admin.js***

```
import AuthenticatorBase from 'simple-auth-oauth2/authenticators/oauth2';
var CustomAuthenticator = AuthenticatorBase.extend({
    serverTokenEndpoint:            AppchatENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverTokenEndpoint,
    serverTokenRevokationEndpoint:  AppchatENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverRevokationTokenEndpoint,
    refreshAccessTokens:            AppchatENV['simple-auth-admin'].refreshAccessTokens
});
console.log("AuthenticatorBase A ",AuthenticatorBase);
console.log("CustomAuthenticator B ",CustomAuthenticator);

export default {
    name:   'simple-auth-admin',
    before: 'simple-auth',
    initialize: function(container) {
        container.register('simple-auth-authenticator:admin', CustomAuthenticator);
    }
};
```

But the above shows an error of "AuthenticatorBase A (unknown mixin)"

and then in 
***file: app/controllers/admin/login.js***

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';
export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
    authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:admin'
}
```

and for the configs...

***file: config/environment.js***

```
ENV['simple-auth-admin'] = {
    serverTokenEndpoint: "http://www.domain.com/admintoken",
    serverTokenRevokationEndpoint: "http://www.domain.com/admintoken/revoke",
    refreshAccessTokens: true
  };
```

EDIT:

so by setting: in file:  ***app/initializers/simple-auth-admin.js***

```
import AuthenticatorBase from 'simple-auth-oauth2/authenticators/oauth2';
var CustomAuthenticator = AuthenticatorBase.extend({
    serverTokenEndpoint:            MyappENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverTokenEndpoint,
    serverTokenRevokationEndpoint:  MyappENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverRevokationTokenEndpoint,
    refreshAccessTokens:            MyappENV['simple-auth-admin'].refreshAccessTokens
});

console.log("AuthenticatorBase.serverTokenEndpoint =",AuthenticatorBase.serverTokenEndpoint);
console.log("CustomAuthenticator.serverTokenEndpoint =",CustomAuthenticator.serverTokenEndpoint);
console.log("MyappENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverTokenEndpoint =  ",MyappENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverTokenEndpoint);

export default {
    name:   'simple-auth-admin',
    before: 'simple-auth',
    initialize: function(container) {
        container.register('simple-auth-authenticator:admin', CustomAuthenticator);
        console.log("[at container.register] CustomAuthenticator.serverTokenEndpoint =  ",CustomAuthenticator.create().get('serverTokenEndpoint'));

    }
};
```

I get output of:

```
AuthenticatorBase.serverTokenEndpoint = undefined
CustomAuthenticator.serverTokenEndpoint = undefined
MyappENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverTokenEndpoint =  http://www.domain.com/oauth2/admintoken
[at container.register] CustomAuthenticator.serverTokenEndpoint = http://www.domain.com/oauth2/admintoken
```

Am I misuderstanding what AuthenticatorBase.extend () is doing?  I thought it would allow you to override some variables or functions?

**EDIT 2:**

***file: app/controllers/admin/login.js***

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var $ = Ember.$;
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';
export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
    authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:admin',
    init: function(){
        console.log('INIT LOGIN CONTROLLER', this.get('session'));
        this._super();
    },
    actions: {
        authenticate: function() { // (data)
            console.log("LoginController clicked");
            $('#nameBtn').ladda().ladda('start');
            console.log(this.get('session'));

            console.log('this.authenticator = ', this.authenticator);
            var _this = this;
            this._super().then(null, function(data) {
                console.log('LOGIN GOT BACK: ', data);
                $('#nameBtn').ladda().ladda('stop');
                    if(data.error !== undefined && data.error !== "") {
                    _this.set('data', {error: data.error});
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This results in an ajax to **www.domain.com/token** rather than the expected **www.domain.com/admintoken**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a lot of coding in circles and trial and error and with a lot of help from:

https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/6-custom-server.html

this is how I achieved what I wanted...

1) Setup the enpoints as variables in the environment file (simple-auth-admin is the name i chose for my admin authenticator)

File:  ***/app/config/environment.js***

```
ENV['simple-auth-admin'] = {
    serverTokenEndpoint: "http://www.domain.com/admintoken",
    serverTokenRevokationEndpoint: "http://www.domain.com/admintoken/revoke",
    refreshAccessTokens: true
};
```

2) Create the actual authenticator as an override in an initialiser Note: in this case the CustomAuthorizer is not actually used and make sure you replace AppNameENV  with your app name, so if your app was called **bob** it would be **BobENV**.

File: ***/app/initializers/simple-auth-admin.js***

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatorBase from 'simple-auth/authenticators/base';
import AuthorizerBase from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';

var CustomAuthorizer = AuthorizerBase.extend({
authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('session.token'))) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token: ' + this.get('session.token'));
    }
}
});

var CustomAuthenticator = AuthenticatorBase.extend({
tokenEndpoint: window.AppNameENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverTokenEndpoint,
tokenRevokationEndpoint: window.AppNameENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverRevokationTokenEndpoint,
refreshAccessTokens: window.AppNameENV['simple-auth-admin'].refreshAccessTokens,
init: function(){
    console.log("CUSOTMM AUTH INIT ",window.AppNameENV['simple-auth-admin'].serverTokenEndpoint);
    this._super();
},
restore: function(data) {
    console.log('AdminAuth - restore');
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.token)) {
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            reject();
        }
    });
},
authenticate: function(credentials) {
    console.log('AdminAuth - authenticate',credentials);
    var _this = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: _this.tokenEndpoint,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ grant_type: 'password', username: credentials.identification, password: credentials.password, session: { identification: credentials.identification, password: credentials.password } }),
                    contentType: 'application/json'
                }).then(function(response) {
                    Ember.run(function() {
                        resolve({ token: response.access_token });
                    });
                }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    Ember.run(function() {
                        reject(response.error);
                    });
                });
        });
    },
    invalidate: function() {
        console.log('AdminAuth - invalidate');
        var _this = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
            Ember.$.ajax({ url: _this.tokenEndpoint, type: 'DELETE' }).always(function() {
            resolve();
            })
        });
    }
});

export default {
    name:   'simple-auth-admin',
    before: 'simple-auth',
    initialize: function(container) {
        console.log("OVERRIDES : ", window.AppNameENV['simple-auth-admin']);
        container.register('simple-auth-authenticator:admin', CustomAuthenticator);
        container.register('simple-auth-authorizer:admin', CustomAuthorizer);
    }
};
```

3) The I setup a redirect route to admin/login for any protected pages ( this example is for **/admin/dashboard**)

File: ***/app/routes/admin/dashboard.js***

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,{
    authenticationRoute: 'admin.login',
    actions: {
        authenticateSession: function() {
            this.transitionTo(this.authenticationRoute);
        }
    }
});
```

4) Then configure the admin controller to use the new custom authenticator

File: ***/app/controllers/admin/login.js***

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var $ = Ember.$;
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';
//import Session from 'simple-auth/session';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
    authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:admin',
});
```

All of which seems a bit heavy handed when all i really wanted to do was have the authentication for the /admin/login point to a different serverendpoint.  Marco, is there a way of overriding just those variables and therefore extend the **simple-auth-oauth2** authorizer?

Answer (score 1):

The routes you're defining are necessary of course.

Since your authorizer and authenticator for the admin area seem to be customized as well those are necessary as well of course. If you used the plain OAuth 2.0 ones for the admin area as well you could drop the authorizer and change the authenticator to

```
import AuthenticatorBase from 'simple-auth-oauth2/authenticators/oauth2';

var CustomAuthenticator = AuthenticatorBase.extend({
  serverTokenEndpoint:           'http://www.domain.com/admintoken',
  serverTokenRevokationEndpoint: 'http://www.domain.com/admintoken/revoke'
});
```

Comment: yey, that looks more straight forward.  could you edit your answer to: 

import AuthenticatorBase from 'simple-auth-oauth2/authenticators/oauth2';

am just testing now and will accept this as the answer if it works for me :)

Comment: hmm, I must be doing something wrong as the serverTokenEndpoint seems to default to the orginal /token instead of /tokenadmin.  All I did was rem out all my CustomAuthenticator code in the initialiser and put your suggestion in instead... hmm..

Comment: further to this, if I console.log the **CustomAuthenticator** (withing the export default initialize function) I get:
***TOKENENPOINT (unknown mixin)***.  And, if I try to console.log the **CustomAuthenticator.serverTokenEndpoint** I get ***undefined*** any thoughts? - thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: Hi @marcoow I was wondering if you had any thoughts on why the **"unknown mixin"** error is occurring with your above suggested answer? - thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code of your custom authenticator?

Comment: I stopped using a custom authenticator and was just trying to override the destination endpoint as per your snippet above and then in the initialize function i simply had: **container.register('simple-auth-authenticator:admin', CustomAuthenticator);**

Comment: The issue is that if I put **console.log("CustomAuthenticator B ",CustomAuthenticator);** directly after your code i get the **unknown mixin** error

Comment: You're using a custom authenticator when `CustomAuthenticator` exists. Can you post the code? Also are you using Ember CLI?

Comment: Hi, see my new Answer detailing the code I am now trying.  Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Every time Ember Simple Auth enforces authentication (usually when a user accesses an authenticated route while the session is not authenticated), it calls the [`ApplicationRouteMixin`'s `authenticateSession` action](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-ApplicationRouteMixin-authenticateSession). The best option you have is to override that and somehow decide whether to transition to the admin or the guest login page from there. If you have e.g. your admin pages namespaces in an `/admin` route, you could also override the `authenticateSession` on the `AdminRoute` and transition to the admin login page from there while the default implementation in the `ApplicationRoute` transitions to the guest login page.

For the authenticators it's probably best to use the default OAuth 2.0 authenticator with its `serverTokenEndpoint` to authenticate guests and extend another authenticator from that that authenticates admin against a different `serverTokenEndpoint`.

Comment: Thanks Marco, do you have a recommended location for the override or should I just try in /app/routes/admin.js ?

Comment: Sure, simply define that in your admin route (which will effectively override that action for all routes beyond that admin route).